# how to change a value in an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have this array of objects:

```
const indexStates = [ {"4": true}, {"3": false}, {"7": false}, {"1": true} ];
```

and am trying to figure out how to change the value in a given object in this original array (do not want to make a copy of the array).  I have tried this

```
index = 4;
indexStates.filter(o => o[index] = !o[index]);
console.log(indexStates);
```

but the result is

```
    [{"4": false}, {"3": false, "4": true}, {"4": true, "7": false}, {"1": true, "4": true}]
```

instead of changing the value only in `{"4": false}` and leaving the other objects as is.  What am I doing wrong?  Also, I don't want to use third party libraries for this operation.

Comment: Well, for one thing you're using `filter` for side effects. `filter`'s purpose is to take an array and create a new array with some of the elements removed (filtered).

Comment: Well, that's close but there is a structural difference with this array of objects compared to the one in the link provided.  The difference is that this array is not structured in the typical format of `[{key: 4, value: false}, {key: 3, value: false}...` and so I'm finding it difficult to work with because the keys are dynamic in a sense.

Comment: FYI: filter creates a new array with references to the old elements. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Yeah, you'd have to do something like `if (index in projects[i]) {` instead of `if (projects[i].value == value) {`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are basically saying is:
filter this array to bring you only the items that the following action:

```
index "4" should be assigned with the opposite value
```

results into true, which means that the items that do not have index 4 (meaning its false in js) will be updated too.

What you need to do is:

```
console.log(indexStates.map(o => o[index] !== undefined ? {[index]: !o[index]} : o))
```

which will return a new array for you to use.

Comment: Were you able to get this to work in a snippet?  I'm getting this result when I run it: `[{"4": true}, {"4": false}, {"4": false}, {"4": false}]`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sv17eLht/

Answer (score 1):

Few comments for your code:

```
index = 4;
indexStates.filter(o => o[index] = !o[index]);
```

this 'index' should be a property name, not a position in the array, and with `o[index] = !o[index]` its a assignment, not a predicate

Instead, Try this

```js
var indexStates = [ {"4": true}, {"3": false}, {"7": false}, {"1": true} ];
var index = 4;
var toChange = indexStates.filter(o => Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o).filter(n => n == index)[0] !== undefined)[0];
toChange[index] = !toChange[index]

console.log(toChange);
console.log(indexStates);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't make a copy of the array... then you could do this:

```
const getIndexOfTarget = (states, target) => {
  const value = states.find(state => Object.keys(state)[0] === target)
  return states.indexOf(value)
}

const states = [{"4": true}, {"3": false}, {"7": false}, {"1": true}];
const target = String(4)
const itemToChange = getIndexOfTarget(states, target)

states[itemToChange][target] = false // or !states[itemToChange][target]
```

Note I cast the `index`, or in this case `target`, to a `String` because that's what the key types are in the objects (you could just put `"4"` if you own it).

If you're going to have multiple "index" of the same value, then you'd need to swap the `find` with a `filter`.

```
const getIndexesOfTarget = (states, target) => {
  const values = states.filter(state => Object.keys(state)[0] === target)
  return values.map(val => states.indexOf(value))
}

const itemsToChange = getIndexesOfTarget(states, target)
itemsToChange.forEach(item => states[item][target] = !states[item][target])
```

Comment: This might not work if the desired target is available more than once in the provided array.

Comment: Correct, it definitely won't work with multiple indexes of the same value. If that's likely to be the case, a for loop would be preferable for sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to create a copy, you should go for `for` loop and check if the key/object exists int the current object and verify. If the value is there then negate it. Below is the snippet for the same. Hope this helps

```js
const indexStates = [ {"4": true}, {"3": false}, {"7": false}, {"1": true} ];

index = "4";
const length = indexStates.length;

for(let i =0; i< length; i++) {
  let elem = indexStates[i];
  if(elem[index]) elem[index] = !elem[index]
}
console.log(indexStates);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a foreach approach

```
const indexStates = [ {"4": true}, {"3": false}, {"7": false}, {"1": true} ];

indexStates.forEach(elem => {
       if(typeof elem[index] === 'undefined') return elem;
       elem[index] = !elem[index];
       return elem;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `forEach`. You can do it like this, if I understand your question correctly:

```js
var indexStates = [ {"4": true}, {"3": false}, {"7": false}, {"1": true} ];
var target = '4';
indexStates.forEach(val=>{
    if(Object.keys(val).includes(target)) val[target]=!val[target];
});
console.log(indexStates);
```